# How can I handle secondary authentication in Google Mail from Perl?

Tags: perl, authentication, smtp, gmail

This is a pure Google Mail question.
I am accessing Google Mail via Perl's Net::SMTP::SSL module.
From time to time the authentication fails not because of a bad password, but because of some additional password check.
The only way to unlock it is via the web interface with an additional entry of text presented as an image. 
Has anyone seen a similar issue and knows a fix. I looked at the Google forums, but did not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this problem because the method you are using to access Gmail is not supported by Google and I am fairly sure it is a violation of their [TOS](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS?hl=en) (see 5.3).  If you wish to access Gmail from inside of a program I would suggest using either its [IMAP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-IMAPClient/lib/Mail/IMAPClient.pod) or [POP3](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mail-POP3Client/POP3Client.pm) interface with the appropriate Perl module.

Since you seem to be sending mail, you should use their [SMTP](http://lifehacker.com/software/email-apps/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server-111166.php) interface with one of [Perl's SMTP modules](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SMTP-TLS/lib/Net/SMTP/TLS.pm).  You may find Google's information about setting up [IMAP clients](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=78799) helpful.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - but I am only sending and not receiving mail at the moment.

Comment: To clarify Chas's update, try using Net::SMTP::TLS instead of Net::SMTP::SSL.